# Save Form Data to database Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database

Am trying to save the form data into my database 
but for some reason I keep getting an error.

Am fairly new to ruby so am not too sure what the problem is.
Am trying to create a new book entry and here is what I have so far.

books.controller

```
class BooksController < ApplicationController

  def new 
    @book = Book.new
  end 

  def create
    @book = Book.new(book_params)
    if @book.save
        redirect_to new_book_path
    end
  end

  private

  def book_params
    params.require(:book).permit(:title, :description, :author, :status, :isbn_number)
  end

end
```

There error am getting is:

```
NameError in BooksController#create
undefined local variable or method `new_book_path' for #<BooksController:0xe3f5ae8>
```

I have a form that I fill in all those details but when I try to submit, I get that error. Its saying the error is on the redirect but I don't know whats wrong.

routes

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  resources :books, :only => [:new, :create]

  get 'page/books'

  get 'page/about'

  get 'page/contact'

  get 'page/home'

  devise_for :users 
  # The priority is based upon order of creation: first created -> highest priority.
  # See how all your routes lay out with "rake routes".

  # You can have the root of your site routed with "root"
   root 'page#home'
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

looks like your routes file has an issue:
your config/routes.rb file should have the following
resources :books, :only => [:new, :create]

For a more complete answer:

The error you are getting is saying the line

```
 redirect_to new_book_path
```

is throwing an error because it does not understand the variable new_book_path.
This variable gets created/handled via your routes file.

Comment: Okay i added that line in and it seems to work. after adding that do i now have to change the way i nav to the new , create ? but Thank you anyway i originally just had resources :books in my routes

Comment: If you share your route file, we can go through it. I have a feeling you have default routing in place.

Comment: i have added it into the question

Answer (score 0):

Just try changing this line

```
redirect_to new_book_path
```

to

```
render 'new'
```